# Search value in array from comma separated value in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [data] => PHP
            [attribs] => Array
                (
                )

            [xml_base] => 
            [xml_base_explicit] => 
            [xml_lang] => 
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [data] => Wordpress
            [attribs] => Array
                (
                )

            [xml_base] => 
            [xml_base_explicit] => 
            [xml_lang] => 
        )
)
```

one varialbe like **$var = 'Php, Joomla';**

I have tried following but not working

```
$key = in_multiarray('PHP', $array,"data");
function in_multiarray($elem, $array,$field)
    {
        $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
        $bottom = 0;
        while($bottom <= $top)
        {
            if($array[$bottom][$field] == $elem)
                return true;
            else 
                if(is_array($array[$bottom][$field]))
                    if(in_multiarray($elem, ($array[$bottom][$field])))
                        return true;

            $bottom++;
        }        
        return false;
    }
```

so want to check if any value in $var is exists in array(case insensitive)

How can i do it without loop?

Comment: Loop trough it. What have you done. Show some effort

Comment: foreach() explode() and buisnesslogic are your firends

Comment: @Bhumi Shah , is this your real array , can the array depth be more than this ?

Comment: @h2ooooooo : see above i have added code i tried

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya : yes, it's real array

Comment: @BhumiShah Without loop you can not get the values , we are programmers man , not magicians :o

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya: loop is fine but within function like i have used in_multiarray. I pass $var and $array ,function return

Comment: so you mean you only need loops , with out recursive function calls ?

Comment: @Kanishka Panamaldeniya: No, i mean i m fine with loop in function. You can do changes in function i provided

Comment: @BhumiShah so you need the aabouve code to be working , that's it right :)

Comment: No one has answer but everyone is ready for minus vote.

Comment: No you got a answer and and upvote :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

(Put a few comments in the code the explain whats goning on)

```
<?php

    //Array to search in
    $array = array(
                array(
                    "data" => "PHP",
                    "attribs" => array(),
                    "xml_base" => "",
                    "xml_base_explicit" => "", 
                    "xml_lang" => ""
                ),
                array(
                "data" => "Wordpress",
                "attribs" => array(),
                "xml_base" => "",
                "xml_base_explicit" => "",
                "xml_lang" => "Joomla"
                )
            );  

    //Values to search
    $var = "Php, Joomla";

    //trim and strtolower all search values and put them in a array 
    $search = array_map(function($value) {
                    return trim(strtolower($value));
    }, explode(",", $var));

    //function to put all non array values into lowercase
    function tolower($value) {

        if(is_array($value))
            return array_map("tolower", $value);
        else
            return strtolower($value);

    }

    //Search needle in haystack
    function in_array_r($needle, $haystack, $strict = false) {
        foreach ($haystack as $item) {
            if (($strict ? $item === $needle : $item == $needle) || (is_array($item) && in_array_r($needle, $item, $strict))) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    //Search ever value in array
    foreach($search as $value) {

        if(in_array_r($value, array_map("tolower", array_values($array))))
            echo $value . " found<br />";
    }

?>
```

Output:

```
php found
joomla found
```

Comment: Thanks. it's working for fix value but if i have $var = 'Php 5.4, Joomla'; then also work?

Comment: @BhumiShah If you have the value also in the array it will work: e.g.: `"xml_base" => "PHP 5.4",` and you have: `$var = 'pHp 5.4, Joomla';` then it will works yes

Comment: Value is not in array but PHP = PHP 5.4 so it have to give value

Comment: @BhumiShah No then it will not work because of the 5.4 which is different!

Answer (score 0):

to my understanding , you are trying to pass the string ex : 'php' and the key : 'data' of the element .
so your key can hold a single value or an array .

```
    $key = in_multiarray("php", $array,"data");
    var_dump($key);
    function in_multiarray($elem, $array,$field)
    {
            $top = sizeof($array) - 1;
            $bottom = 0;
            while($bottom <= $top)
            {

                 if(is_array($array[$bottom][$field]))
                 {
                    foreach($array[$bottom][$field] as $value)
                    {
                        if(strtolower(trim($value)) == strtolower(trim($elem)))
                        {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                  }
                  else if(strtolower(trim($array[$bottom][$field])) == strtolower(trim($elem))) 
                  {
                    return true;
                  }

                $bottom++;
            }        

       return false;
    }
```

Comment: It not working for comma seperated string  $var = 'Php, Joomla';

Comment: Explode the string and make an array , try to loop using that array , give a try :)